# помогите вырезать дату со временем C#

Tags: c#

Моя проблема заключается в том что мне нужно отрезать часть текста из текстового файла пример:
30.01.2014 10:32:44 36324 36324 36324 36324 2

нужно оставить только дату со временем попытался

```
DateTime.Parse(line.);
```

но после line не знаю что писать чтобы отрезало 19 знаков и вывело на консоль.
Пытался вставить Replace, но оно ищет что нужно заменить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если дата гарантированно занимает 19 символов в начале строки, можно воспользоваться методом [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 19));
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли